# Running cython extension directly using python interpreter? i.e. "python test.so"

Tags: python, cython

I want to compile main.py into main.so and run it using the python interpreter in linux, like this: "/usr/bin/python main.so"

How can i do this?

So far running extensions compiled the official way give me this:

```
root@server:~/TEMP# python test.so 
File "test.so", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\x8b' in file test.so on line 2,...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't execute a .so directly. Cause of the binary form, you have to import it with:

```
python -m test
```

If you want to make an executable out of the module, you could use the "-embed" option of cython:

```
cython -embed test.pyx
gcc ...your flags... test.c -o test
./test
```

Comment: The suggested "python -m" give me the following error:
"/usr/bin/python: No code object available for test"

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute it as a module.

```
python -m test
```

Comment: thanks this helps, but still feels a little dirty, i fish i could do ./test and have it invoke python on its own

Comment: What is the preferred approach for this when you are building an extension module in place (like a sandbox build in some local directory), rather than building it and installing it. When I try `python -m package.subpackage.module` (which corresponds to package/subpackage/module.so locally), it just says "no code object available for package.subpackage.module".